# HDMI not recognised on Lenovo Ideapad 320S + Ubuntu 17.10 (i915 driver)

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi, intel

I have a Lenovo 320S laptop with an Intel i5-8250U processor and Intel UHD Graphics 620. The internal display works without issue, but when I want to connect to my external display, there is no signal. I'm running Gnome with Wayland, but I also tried switching to Xorg to no avail, except that running `xrandr` also said "HDMI-1 disconnected" which didn't show up under Wayland.

```
william@YEN:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+

william@YEN:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for william: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

The Display tab under Settings in Gnome doesn't show anything to indicate that there is another display connected, of course.

[image: (Pic of Display menu)]

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Did you check your BIOS/USRI Settings for anything relating to video?

Comment: @ubfan1 I did! There wasn't anything there, sadly. I googled and found a suggestion to that effect, I should've mentioned that in the post.

Comment: Try to logout, and on the login screen choose "Ubuntu on X.Org" (click the gear icon) and log back in.

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer I tried that as well, as I mentioned in the post the only difference I found was that xrandr returned "HDMI-1 disconnected" despite the cable being plugged in.

Comment: Maybe check the cable or try another cable and maybe another hdmi display. When using a tv, check that the source is actually enabled and using the "scan only" (or alike) setting.

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer Yeah, that was one of the first things I tried actually. What I'm using is a HDMI cable connected to a HDMI->DisplayPort adapter, plugged into the monitor. When it didn't work, I tried using a straight up HDMI->DP cable, which also did not work. The monitor recognises that a cable is plugged in, but it says "no signal". I've tried both the auto setting and the DP setting for input on the monitor.

Comment: Okay, so! It turns out plugging the HDMI cable straight into a TV works, so it would seem that the issue lies with using a HDMI->DP converter. Sorry for not thinking to try this before.

Comment: Found the issue. I accidentally bought a DP->HDMI adapter instead of a HDMI->DP adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: I had accidentally bought a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter, rather than a HDMI to DisplayPort adapter, which is most likely what caused the problem.